# Admin panel not working without language code in url in CraftCms2

Tags: locale, admin, craftcms

I've migrated a website with CraftCms 2 from local to a pre-production server. Everything is working fine but, I don't know why, I only can go to the admin panel with locale code before /admin. I mean, if I write domain.com/admin, it doesn't work. But if I write domain.com/es/admin it works. And this don't happen in local server, only in pre-production.

I get message "Not Found. The requested URL /admin was not found on this server." Instead of a 404 from my webpage.

It works fine in others projects under craft with the same structure and, as I said, in local server works fine too. In root I have:

- assets/
- craft/
- en/
- va/
- es/
- index.php

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I left an .htaccess file in root. It wasn't in local server neither, but It seems it was some config in virtual host or something like that to solve it. Once I find this .htaccess in other craft project, was solved ;)

Don't forget your .htaccess in root!